# php query string with spaced column name alias

Tags: php, postgresql

Below is part of a sql query I am sending as string via php which runs successfully. All I need to do is change the column name (containing '_') to spaces.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(g.test_case_id), test_case_path AS test_case, build_name, g.total_files_covered, g.total_files_in_build, round(cast(g.total_files_covered as numeric)/cast(g.total_files_in_build as numeric),4)*100 as file_coverage, g.total_functions_covered , g.total_functions_in_build, round(cast(g.total_functions_covered as numeric)  / cast(g.total_functions_in_build as numeric) ,4)*100 as function_coverage,run_duration AS run_duration_in_seconds FROM ( .... )
```

For example, the last column name is `run_duration_in_seconds` change that to `run duration in seconds` . When i use block quotes around column name alias (with spaces) to execute query from my php function. I get error:

```
Warning: pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near &amp;quot;`&amp;quot;
LINE 2: ...ric) ,4)*100 as function_coverage,run_duration AS `run durat...
```

How should I add column name alias (with spaces instead of underscore) to the query so that it can be run by the php pg_query function ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using quotes with escapes around your alias (though not needed if query is in single quotation marks)? Like

```
$query = "Select field as \"run duration in seconds\" from table"
```

or

```
$query = 'Select field as "run duration in seconds" from table'
```